# How to stop a Lottie animation at a certain time in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lottie

I have created a Lottie animation for my logo, in my website. I wanted it to play only once at the beginning of the loading page and when the user hovers over it and I did it  using `:hover` autoplay. The problem is after it loads for the first time or when the user done with hovering it, I want it to stop at a certain point where the logo is completed, so it looks like a fixed logo.

This is the code for my Lottie animation logo:

```
<lottie-player src="https://lottie.host/afffd6d7-bf1f-46e1-8593-0bbe2f99ca00/ONeoa9me40.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 70px; height: 120px;" hover autoplay></lottie-player>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using you need to disable looping or else it will keep playing the Lottie File.

```
<lottie-player src="https://lottie.host/afffd6d7-bf1f-46e1-8593-0bbe2f99ca00/ONeoa9me40.json" background="transparent" loop={false} speed="1" style="width: 70px; height: 120px;" hover ></lottie-player>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your code. It works perfectly now. The animation plays once when the page is loaded for the first time or refreshed, and the image becomes static. Additionally, when the cursor hovers over the logo, the animations start playing again from the beginning.

**Add one more external script file to your code after the first one presently in your code.**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js"></script>
```

**The following changes to LottiePlayer tag**

```
<lottie-player id="myLottie" src="https://lottie.host/afffd6d7-bf1f-46e1-8593-0bbe2f99ca00/ONeoa9me40.json"
        background="transparent" style="width: 140px; height: 240px;"></lottie-player>
```

**Simple JS for interaction with animation**

```
<script>
    LottieInteractivity.create({
        mode: 'chain',
        player: '#myLottie',
        actions: [

            {
                state: 'autoplay',
                transition: 'hover',
                frames: [0, 114],
            },
            {
                type: 'hold',
                state: 'autoplay',
                transition: 'onComplete',
                reset: true,
            }
        ],
    });
</script>
```